# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager PluginClassLoader

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, plugins

I am developing a IDEA plugin, I wrote a action class to get MavenProject(org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject) instance of project.
here is the code:

```
package com.example.demo.actions;

import com.intellij.ide.IdeView;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.LangDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiDirectory;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiFile;
import org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager;

public class ProjectViewPopupMenuTestAction extends AnAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        IdeView ideView = e.getData(LangDataKeys.IDE_VIEW);
        if (ideView == null) {
            return;
        }

        PsiDirectory chooseDirectory = ideView.getOrChooseDirectory();
        PsiFile psiFile = chooseDirectory.findFile("pom.xml");
        VirtualFile virtualFile = psiFile.getVirtualFile();
        MavenProject mavenProject = MavenProjectsManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).findProject(virtualFile);
        System.out.println(mavenProject);
    }
}
```

in plugin.xml, I add ProjectViewPopupMenuTestAction to ProjectViewPopupMenu:

```
    <actions>
        <action id="pomProjectViewPopup" class="com.example.demo.actions.ProjectViewPopupMenuTestAction"
                text="getPomDependency" description="ProjectViewPopupMenu">
            <add-to-group group-id="ProjectViewPopupMenu" anchor="last"/>
        </action>
    </actions>
```

I need maven plugin,so I added maven plugin in intellij block. here is my build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.13.3"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Configure Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
// Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html
intellij {
    version.set("2022.2.4")
    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform

    plugins.set(listOf("maven"))
}

tasks {
    // Set the JVM compatibility versions
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "11"
        targetCompatibility = "11"
    }
    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    patchPluginXml {
        sinceBuild.set("222")
        untilBuild.set("232.*")
    }

    signPlugin {
        certificateChain.set(System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_CHAIN"))
        privateKey.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
        password.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD"))
    }

    publishPlugin {
        token.set(System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN"))
    }
}
```

Question:

when i debug the code, it threws ClassNotFoundException while run with:

```
MavenProject mavenProject = MavenProjectsManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).findProject(virtualFile);
```

com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil:336:

```
AccessToken ignore = SlowOperations.allowSlowOperations(SlowOperations.ACTION_PERFORM)
```

and then goto 345, threw the NoClassDefFoundError:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ahg2.png)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Demo, id=com.example.demo, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/java/IDEAPlugin/demo/build/idea-sandbox/plugins/demo, version=1.0-SNAPSHOT, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=73, state=active)
```

but I stopped in breakpoint[VirtualFile virtualFile = psiFile.getVirtualFile();] and opened evaluate window to excute the rest code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2zIj.png)

It works!!!

I am really confused by this exception over 5 days. please.

my environment:
Development IDEA: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 Build #IU Mac OS X

plugin debug environment:
2023-04-27 11:27:07,938 [ 63374] SEVERE - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 Build #IC-222.4459.24

2023-04-27 11:27:07,944 [ 63380] SEVERE - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - JDK: 17.0.5; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.

2023-04-27 11:27:07,945 [ 63381] SEVERE - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X

I have looked for some same open-source plugin code, our code is similar, and google so many times, no result. please.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.

Comment: thx, I have posted it.